# Nodemailer with gmail

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, nodemailer

I at first tried the simple approach without the OAuth2 with it did not work after a lot of tries email did get sent but only 2 or 3 time that too on chance, i read many post most of them recommended oauth2 so i implemented it but it still does not work i hope you guys can help.
here's the code without oauth2 for this i enabled and imap and 2fa and created custom password

```
export const sendEmail = (options) => {

    
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        port: 587,
        type: "SMTP",
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        secure: true,// for port 587 it should be false but this worked a few times so i let it be
        auth: {
            
            user: EMAIL_FROM,
            pass: EMAIL_PASSWORD,
        },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: EMAIL_FROM,
        to: options.to,
        subject: options.subject,
        html: options.text,
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(info);
        }
    });
};
```

and now the on with oauth2

```
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,REDIRECT_URI);
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token:REFRESH_TOKEN});

export const sendEmail = async(options) => {

    try {
        
        const accessToken = (await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken()).token
        console.log(accessToken,REDIRECT_URI,REFRESH_TOKEN,CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET)
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: "gmail",
            host: "smtp.gmail.com",
            port: 587,
            //port: 465,
    
            secure : false, // true for 465, false for other ports
            //type: "SMTP",
            //secure: true,
            auth: {
                type:"OAuth2",
                user: "my email",
                clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                accessToken,
                clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
                refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
                //pass: EMAIL_PASSWORD,
            },
        });
    
        const mailOptions = {
            from: "my email",
            to: options.to,
            subject: options.subject,
            text:"Password change",
            html: options.text,
        };
    
        const result = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        return result;
        
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
    
};
```

I tried almost all the previous given solutions i could find but the error is always almost same only the address changes. I even tried send grid still nothing(Started with this)

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.68.109:465
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16) {
> errno: -4039,
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '74.125.68.109',
> port: 465,
> command: 'CONN'
> }

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of nodemailer

Answer (score 0):

The error `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` is unrelated to apps password or Oauth2.  Make sure you have the latest version of nodemailer.  I am using `"nodemailer": "^6.8.0"`

## apps password

To send an email using smtp you need to enable 2fa on your google account and crate an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).  Then you simply us the apps password in place of the users standard google password.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
async function main() {
    // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
    // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
    let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
            pass: '[AppsPassword]',
        },
    });

    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: '"Linda Lawton " <xxx@gmail.com>', // sender address
        to: "xxx@gmail.com", // list of receivers
        subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
        text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
        html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
    });

    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

}

main().catch(console.error);
```

This is a C# example of how to fix it it shows you how to create an apps password. [Quick fix for SMTP username and password not accepted error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI&t=73s)

Comment: I have already created app password it still did not work thats why i used oauth2. And thanks for the edit .

Comment: Apps password does work.  Please check my code its what i use for my clients all the time.  Apps password is a much easer solution then adding Oauth2 with Oauth2 your going to have to handle any issues with expired refresh tokens.

Comment: Its working now but i don't know why, with app password and oauth2. So i think ill remove ouath2

Comment: I would defiantly avoid oauth2 if you can.  I dont have a sample for that right now but if your curious I may be able to find sometime next week to put one together.